# "Interface" classes to access ancillary computations of a base class

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I am wondering how to best (in terms of efficiency and readability) implement a design pattern involving a base class and 2 interface classes (I1 and I2) that access a class A that performs some relatively time consuming operations

Let's assume we have a base class A that has a method:

```
class A {

  // methods ...

  double computeValue(double in1, double in2, double& out1) {


      double result;

      /* Perform some very time consuming computations with in1 and in2, 
         that leads to some intermediate values and the result */

      // Compute side product from those intermediate values that took so long
      // to obtain
      out1 = intermediate_value1 * intermediate_value2;

      return result;
  }

  // more methods and members

}
```

Now let's assume we have an interface class (I1) that is exclusively interested in returning A's "result" value:

```
// Interface class to A
class I1 {

  public:

    // ctor, dtor, ...

    double getResult(){double in1, in2, out1; return pA_->computeValue(in1, in2, out1);}

  private:

    std::shared_ptr<A> pA_;
}
```

On the other hand, I need a second Interface class that is only interested in `out1`, the side product of `computeValue`.

```
// Interface class to A
class I2 {

  public:

    double getResult(){double in1, in2, out1; pA_->computeValue(in1, in2, out1); return out1;}

  private:

    std::shared_ptr<A> pA_;
}
```

I could split `computeValue` in separate methods, the problem is that the values `out1` and `result` should be derived from exactly the same inputs (and I do not want to repeat the execution of `computeValue` as it can be an "expensive" method in terms of load)

I was wondering if there is any design pattern that could help me implement this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: the two interfaces ares supposed to be used by two different clients that both have the input?

Comment: @tobi303 The two interfaces would be called by the same client and, therefore, will have the same input

Comment: It seems that the function `compute_value` actually computes two values. It could be refactored to return a tuple of two elements, and you may use `std::ignore` to disregard one in either of your calls.

Comment: @hauron Thanks! but then shouldn't I have to call computeValue twice? That is what I would like to avoid if possible...

Comment: @mgfernan your previous approach wouldn't protect you from that either. If you wish to avoid calling it twice, consider caching it: either a single "last computed" value, or a set of these - google LRU cache. Instead of caching you could of course implement a wrapper struct for these two elements, and move that around (a bit unrelated, but look up Command design pattern).